# Data Structures and Algorithm Book for C

Tags: c

What is a popular/good data structures and algorithm analysis book for C other than
Data Structures, Algorithms, and Software Principles in C by Thomas Standish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best book for learning about Algorithms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302270/what-is-the-best-book-for-learning-about-algorithms)

Comment: As a rule, you shouldn't care about the implementation language for an algorithms and data structures book. You'll probably need to adapt it to the context anyway - e.g. a data structure in a file will be implemented a little differently to the same data structure in memory. Some books spoon-feed more than others, and I have no problem with that, but you should understand enough that translating to another language is no issue. The main exception is books targeting functional languages like Haskell, where specialised methods apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, and Clifford Stein is considered the standard reading on this subject. It's very thorough.

Comment: Please provide a reason for the downvote.

Comment: Coremen book is a waste ,try SedgeWick instead

Comment: This book is hard to read  for beginner, and not practical. `<The Algorithm Design Manual 2nd>` is so much better.

Answer (score 9):

[Algorithms in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201314525) (Sedgewick) is also good

[The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) is very readable

Comment: I've heard good things about this one.

Comment: @SaadQureshi - actually Sedgwick rocks

Comment: @MartinBeckett Its correct already check ,http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/

Comment: @SaadQureshi - sorry it was a joke! Adam Sedgwick (no e) invented the science of Geology

Comment: I have read many books on algorithm, `<The Algorithm Design Manual 2nd>` is the only one that I felt interesting & practical ! It’s very fun & useful!