# Unique numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

Similar to my previous question, this time I am trying to print the numbers which do not occur twice or more than twice.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[10]={2,2,2,4,6,6,9,10,10,11};
    for(i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i] != a[i+1] && i!=9)
        {    if(i > 0 && a[i] != a[i-1])
             printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
        if(i==9 && a[i]!=a[i-1])
             printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output comes out to be correct i.e 4,9,11 but I need to consider the final value of i separately. Is there a better way?

Comment: Don't dual tag code as C and C++.  That's not C++, and it is only archaic (C89) C code.  You should be using `int main()` at the least.  And, since you're using C89, you shouldn't omit the `return 0;` from `main()` either; that's only allowed in C99 or later.

Comment: Is it fine now? Please let me know if it is still incorrect.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour because it access `a[10]` before it checks that `i != 9`.  That's bad news.  (Yes, the updated code looks OK apart from the undefined behaviour.  You could fix that by setting the upper bound of the loop to 9, somehow.  The scattered 9's and 10's are not very good, though — especially not the 9's.  I'd likely use `const int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);` and loop to `i < n - 1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, I do know about that and I don't like it. This is one of the reasons I posted the problem here.

Comment: Another question. Can you assume that the input array is sorted?

Comment: @SzG: You may work with an unsorted array if you wish to. I think it is simpler to work with a sorted array.

Comment: What SzG means is that do *you* assume that the input array is sorted? Do you understand why that condition is important for the algorithm in your test loop to work? What do you do if your array is *not* sorted?

Comment: @AlexReynolds: No, I do not assume that the user inputs a sorted array and I do understand the code I have written above. I thought it would be easier to work with a sorted array and even if the user inputs a random array, I can sort it with any sorting algorithm.

Comment: If you sort the data, your algorithm goes from linear (_O(N)_) to log-linear (_O(N log N)_) or quadratic (_O(N*N)_).  Your algorithm only works (to the extent it does work) if the data is sorted.  You should identify the sort operation, even if you don't show it, if you are assuming that the data is sorted.  Or you could assert it: `assert(a[i] <= a[i+1]);` in the loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sorry, I have never heard of big-O algorithms you stated.

Comment: If there's a small upper bound on the numbers that are used in the array, then you could create a histogram of the unsorted array, and then print those values that have a histogram entry of 1.

Comment: Well, you've got the delights of 'Big-O' notation still to come, then.  Suffice to say _O(N log N)_ algorithms are usually slower than _O(N)_ but faster than _O(N*N)_.  If you know the data is given in sorted order, you can use an _O(N)_ algorithm like your original, instead of a quadratic algorithm like the one that's currently accepted.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) then learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I will try to learn these algorithms soon. Thank you about the info. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that logical operators have precedence, and upon equal precedence, as in your `if` statements, they are evaluated left to right. so

```
if(a[i] != a[i+1] && i!=9)
```

will evaluate the `a[10]` before `i!=9`, leading to out of bound read. If you change that to

```
if(i!=9 && a[i] != a[i+1])
```

the problem wont happen, as `i!=9` is evaluated before, and since it will be false, the rest is known to be false and not evaluated, no out of bound read.

Better yet, loop on `i=0; i<9` and move the second if outside the loop, eliminating the need for the check `i!=9` entirely.

Moreover, you code will fail for the array `{2,3,.....}`, it will not print the first element
as it should.

Here is a better version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[10]={2,2,2,4,6,6,9,10,10,11};
    for(i=0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i] != a[i+1])
        {    
            if(i == 0 || a[i] != a[i-1])
                printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
    }
    if(a[8] != a[9])
        printf("%d", a[9]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that after the loop, we simply use the proper subscripts. The is more efficient because adding `ifs` to check for the last element will evaluate those `ifs` on every iteration, while now it is evaluated only once.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you once again Khaled.:)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a nested for loop to check the values. This way would also work with an unsorted list.

```
int i;
int j;
int match; 
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    match = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[j] && i!=j)
            match = 1;
            break;
    }
    if (match == 0)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

This code will check each value against all other values and print the numbers that are only found in the list once as per your example.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to check that in the for loop the value of i does not go out of array bound

i think this should work

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[10]={2,2,2,4,6,6,9,10,10,11};
    for(i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i] != a[(i+1)%10])
        {    if(i > 0 && a[i] != a[i-1])
                 printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer

A simplified approach to finding unique values on a sorted array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a[] = { 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11 };
  size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
  int previous = ~a[0];
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] != previous)
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
    previous = a[i];
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```